# Angular incorrectly setting input class as valid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have this input field

```
<input formControlName="fieldName" class="validate" id="fieldName" type="text">
<label for="fieldName">{{field.fieldLabel}}</label>
<ng-container *ngIf="myForm.controls.fieldName.touched && myForm.controls.fieldName.invalid">
     <span class="helper-text" data-error="Error message" *ngIf="myForm.controls.fieldName.errors.pattern"></span>
</ng-container>
```

When I inspect it in console, before typing anything, I get this:

```
<input _ngcontent-lqx-c2="" class="validate ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="fieldName" id="fieldName" type="text" ng-reflect-name="fieldName">
```

After I type a wrong value, I get this:

```
<input _ngcontent-lqx-c2="" class="validate ng-dirty ng-invalid valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="fieldName" id="fieldName" type="text" ng-reflect-name="fieldName">
```

Note that after I type the wrong value, a **valid** class is included, even if the form and the field are invalid.

Bellow, there is a print of my FormControl just after I inserted the wrong value:
[image]

That's is really messing up with all my validation.

I tried to use updateValueAndValidity() on change, but it made no difference.

Also tried to include de following code, that inserts a invalida class, which works only for the first touch and dissapears after you leave the input because another time, the valid class is included.

```
[ngClass]="{ 'invalid': myForm.controls.fieldName.touched && myForm.controls.fieldName.invalid }"
```

Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: The console log says invalid: true when you are entering a wrong value... I don't get what the problem is

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] as a stackblitz reproducing the issue, would really help.